# Regular expression to extract image url from html code

Tags: java, regex, html-parsing, imageurl

I wanted to extract Url of image from html code, e.g. html code below:

```
<div class="imageContainer">
   <img src="http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/41%2B7N48F7JL._SL135_.jpg"
      alt="" width="135" height="94"
      style="margin-top: 21px; margin-bottom:20px;" /></div>
```

And I got a code from net

```
String regexImage = "(?<=<img (*)src=\")[^\"]*";
Pattern pImage = Pattern.compile(regexImage);
Matcher mImage = pImage.matcher(elementString);
while (mImage.find()) {
   String imagePath = mImage.group();}
```

which is working and has re(regular expression)

```
"(?<=<img src=\")[^\"]*"
```

But now I want to extract image url from html code like below :

```
<img onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-logit="true" data-pid="MOBDDDBRHVWQZHYY"
   data-imagesize="thumb"
   data-error-url="http://img1a.flixcart.com/mob/thumb/mobile.jpg"
   src="http://img8a.flixcart.com/image/mobile/h/y/y/samsung-galaxy-s-duos-s7562-125x125-imadddczzr4qhqnc.jpeg"
   alt="Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562: Mobile"
   title="Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562: Mobile"></img></a>
<div class="bp-offer-image image-offer"></div>
```

where there is code between img and src=

I'm trying the regular expression as `"(?<=<img (*)src=\")[^\"]*"`
but its not working. So please give me regular expression so that i can extract image url i.e.  `http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/61xqOQ3Sj8L._SL135_.jpg` from above html code.

And, first I'm using Jsoup to parse html to extract tags containing img :

```
doc = Jsoup.connect(urlFromBrowse).get();
            Elements elements = doc.getElementsByTag("img");

            for (Element element : elements) {
                String elementString = element.toString();
```

and passed this elementString to matcher() meathod. And from the tag(element) that I'm getting, I'm using regular expression to parse image url, name etc things.

Comment: Don't use Regex. Parse it as html code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not

Comment: Parsing well formed html is easy but if isn't well formed it's a nightmare!

Comment: Just saw this on the front page. Surely Java has some DOM parser. Investigate this, rather than regex.

Comment: @Cthulhu please see question because I have edited it. And now tell me, am I doing wrong by parsing it.

Comment: @Aubin :), yes, I am really tired and frustrated now

Comment: thanks for your comments, but hey guys, for 2 weeks I'm working on it, now almost done what I wanted, just remaining is that one correct regular expression. And now I can't start my work from scratch to parse it using other techniques. So anyone please give me that regular expression

Comment: No, you are already using a DOM parser, so use it. Why do it incorrectly when you almost have it right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This post is an answer to the question, not a guideline.

The question was not "RegExp vs DOM", the question was "Regular expression to extract image url from html code".

Here it is:

```
String htmlFragment =
   "<img onerror=\"img_onerror(this);\" data-logit=\"true\" data-pid=\"MOBDDDBRHVWQZHYY\"\n" + 
   "   data-imagesize=\"thumb\"\n" + 
   "   data-error-url=\"http://img1a.flixcart.com/mob/thumb/mobile.jpg\"\n" + 
   "   src=\"http://img8a.flixcart.com/image/mobile/h/y/y/samsung-galaxy-s-duos-s7562-125x125-imadddczzr4qhqnc.jpeg\"\n" + 
   "   alt=\"Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562: Mobile\"\n" + 
   "   title=\"Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562: Mobile\"></img></a>";
Pattern pattern =
   Pattern.compile( "(?m)(?s)<img\\s+(.*)src\\s*=\\s*\"([^\"]+)\"(.*)" );
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher( htmlFragment );
if( matcher.matches()) {
   System.err.println(
      "OK:\n" +
      "1: '" + matcher.group(1) + "'\n" +
      "2: '" + matcher.group(2) + "'\n" +
      "3: '" + matcher.group(3) + "'\n" );
}
```

and the ouput:

```
OK:
1: 'onerror="img_onerror(this);" data-logit="true" data-pid="MOBDDDBRHVWQZHYY"
   data-imagesize="thumb"
   data-error-url="http://img1a.flixcart.com/mob/thumb/mobile.jpg"
   '
2: 'http://img8a.flixcart.com/image/mobile/h/y/y/samsung-galaxy-s-duos-s7562-125x125-imadddczzr4qhqnc.jpeg'
3: '
   alt="Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562: Mobile"
   title="Samsung Galaxy S Duos S7562: Mobile"></img></a>'
```

Comment: less snarky: how does this handle old, ill-formed HTML better than a DOM parser? How do you know the DOM parser doesn't handle it in the first place?

Comment: hey, you are great, but I think you have made 1 mistake. Because your code works great here, but not in my code. And reason behind it is(I think that), you have used \ before every ", and designed regular expression for it, but in code there are no \. So please give regular expression for it, you are my last hope

Comment: The example code you give contains ". Please, give the url of the real HTML source.

Comment: I'm trying a application like http://pinterest.com/. The above html code sample is a tag from html from http://www.amazon.com/

Comment: `if( matcher.matches() )` may be incorrect in the above example; should it be `while( matcher.find() ) `?

Comment: @Aubin How can I change the src for multiple different images in java using jsoup? Can you help me with this question?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39095067/how-to-change-src-for-multiple-images-in-android

Answer (score 2):

According to the [docs](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html) JSoup (a DOM parser) can easily get the attribute after you have gotten the tag element. Something like

```
doc.getElementsByTag("img").attr("src")
```

ought to work.

For the record I'm a Perl guy, a community that often reaches for regexes too quickly. I am constantly trying to enlighten people to the joy that is using DOM parsers rather than fragile regexes.

Comment: Yes, use DOM for x-html but for ill-formed HTML (3.2) it's not applicable.

Comment: who said anything about ill-formed HTML 3.2?

Comment: this seems like what I wanted, I will try this and will come back. By the way, thanks

Comment: you may have to loop over the tag elements, see the docs for the [`Elements`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) class for helper methods for this.

Comment: thanks for the useful link, because in my eclipse I'm not getting any documentation for mouse hover for any of the JSoup methods.

Answer (score 0):

I'd expect you to be able to get the various attributes of the `<img>` element via the JSoup API. Does [Node.attributes()](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#attributes%28%29) give you what you want ?