# How to change src for multiple images in android?

Tags: java, android, html, jsoup

I want to change source for each and every image in the html content.
After the source has changed I want to display the html content in a webview.
This is the code I am trying to execute.
The problem with this code is it changes all the images to the last image parsed.

```
private void show_webview( String instruction ) {
   ParseJSON pj = new ParseJSON(instruction);
   pj.parseJSON();
   String[] instructions = ParseJSON.instruction;
   for( int i = 0; i < instructions.length; i++ ) {
      instructions[i] = instructions[i].replaceAll("Â"," ");
      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(instructions[i]);
      Elements img = doc.getElementsByTag("img");
      int no_imgs = img.size();
      int im=0;
      String src = null;
      String img_src[] = new String[no_imgs];
      for (Element el:img) {
         src = el.absUrl("src");
         downloadImages(src);
         img_src[im] =src;
         im++;
      }
      for (int x=0; x< img_src.length; x++) {
         int indexname = img_src[x].lastIndexOf("/");
         if (indexname == img_src[x].length()) {
            img_src[x]= img_src[x].substring(x, indexname);
         }
         indexname = img_src[x].lastIndexOf("/");
         String name = img_src[x].substring(indexname, img_src[x].length());
         Log.d("Image name", name);
         Element image1 = doc.select("img").first();
         String img_url = image1.absUrl("src");
         if (img_src[x].contains(name.toLowerCase())) {
            Boolean isSDPresent =
               Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
            if (isSDPresent) {
               Elements image = doc.select("img[src]");
               String imagePath = "file://"+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/rreadyreckoner_images" + name;
               image.attr("src", imagePath);
               Log.d("PATH", imagePath);
            }
            else {
               Elements image = doc.select("img[src]");
               String imagePath = "file://"+"/storage/emulated/0/rreadyreckoner_images"+name;
               image.attr("src", imagePath);
            }
         }
      }
      webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
      webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
      webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
      webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
      webView.loadDataWithBaseURL( "", String.valueOf(doc), "text/html", "utf-8", "" );
      Log.d("Instruction",instructions[i]);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the edit @Aubin Can you help with a solution.

Comment: **Not the most efficient way**  - How about loading the contents of the entire HTML document into a `String` and use `replace` to change the path to `src` ?

Comment: `Elements image = doc.select("img[src]");` isn't enougth restrictive, it lacks the value of src to select only one image. Note `Elements` is plural when `image` isn't, it must be `images`. See https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax